# Cleanup the files in TFS

Tags: tfs

We have added few folders/files in TFS which was deleted later. But, this folders are shown as deleted folders and it seems this can be recovered by performing undelete operation. These files should not have been checked-in in first place. How can I make sure this folders not available in TFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can permanently delete the required version-controlled folders/files from Team Foundation Source control using  the tf destroy command.

Check this MSDN library for detailed info on tf destroy command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can't without directly editing the TFS database (which I really wouldn't recommend).  TFS is a version control system; that includes control of deletions.

You could possibly set security on those specific items to deny anyone access to them, if it's important enough.